# Volume of a tetragonal pyramid

Tags: calculus, volume

Express the volume $V$ of a regular tetragonal pyramid as a  function of its altitude $x$ and the edge of a lateral face (lateral edge) $y$

The answer given by the book is $\frac{2}{3} (y^2 - x^2) x $. But,I've found the lateral edge is $2 \sqrt{y^2 - x^2 } $ and I thought that the area of the basis is $ 4(y^2 - x^2)$. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I don't quite get this. If the lateral edge is $y$, how it is also $2\sqrt{y^2-x^2}$?

Comment: I think the question is not talking about the edge of the base

Comment: You seem to use the term *lateral edge* for two different things. Please clarify your question by editing.

Comment: Well, since I have the original book in my language and in english, I just got question from the english book and put there. But in my language, it is clear it's not talking about the edge of the base.

Comment: Thanks. You just missed a $\sqrt 2$, see below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Denote by $d$ the diagonal of the base. There is a orthogonal triangle with edges $d/2$, $x$ and $y$, so by the Pythagorean theorem 
$$ y^2 = x^2 + \frac 14d^2 $$
that is 
$$ d^2 = 4(y^2 - x^2) \iff d = 2\sqrt{y^2 - x^2}. $$
Now the sidelength $a$ of the base is given by $a = d/\sqrt 2$ (again by Pythagoras), so 
$$ a = \frac d{\sqrt 2} = \sqrt 2 \cdot \sqrt{y^2 - x^2} $$
So the area $A$ of the base is 
$$ A = a^2 = 2 \cdot (y^2 - x^2) $$
and hence the volume 
$$ V = \frac 13 A \cdot x = \frac 23 \cdot (y^2 - x^2). $$

Comment: Thanks! I see what I've did wrong in my resolution.